# Example of writing CSV using StrTk String Toolkit Library

Tags: c++, c, serialization, csv

I just started to learn the [String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html).  I've read the CodeProject article, but it seemed focused on parsing and tokenization.  Can someone point me to an example of using it to serialize a struct array to CSV file?  For example, given:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

I'd like to write an array of Points to a csv file, one point per row.  The int to string conversion should be fast.

Answer (score 11):

I think that best example is [String Toolkit Library Source Code and Examples](http://www.partow.net/downloads/strtk.zip), especially file "strtk_serializer_example.cpp". This example describes many scenarios of structure serialization.